# Добавить в поле String значение из другого класса

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

У меня есть класс1 в котором содержатся `xpath` элементы и есть класс2 в котором я создаю экземпляр класса и хочу передать значение в класс1 в `xpath` элемент. Также в классе 1 я проверяю циклом подставляя каждый раз новое задание, существует ли элемент, затем вывожу значение из этого элемента. Подставляю и проверяю циклом новое значение т.к. эти элементы подгружается таблица и не знаешь сколько строк в ней может быть. 
По дебагу у меня через сеттер значение приходит в класс1, но при вставке в `xpath` оно `null` и соответственно у меня не проходит проверка на существование элемента.
Почему так происходит? И как правильно сделать чтобы работало?

Вот так это примерно выглядит: 
Для определения нахождения элемента есть метод который возвращает `True or False`

```
public class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Test test = new Test();
    int count =1;
   test.setx(count);
  While(проверка на существование элемента: test.xpath) {

System.out.println(test.xpath.getText());
count++;
test.setx(count);

}

    }
}
public class Test{

    public int x;

    public void setx(int x){
        this.x=x;
    }
    public  String xpath= "xpath" + x + " xpath";
}
```

Comment: Что за метод getText() у String-a? Что означает (проверка на существование элемента: test.xpath)? Почему он может перестать существовать? Очевидно, что-то не договариваете...

Comment: test.xpath.getText() строка означает, что берётся текст с элемента на веб странице. Это проверка на то, загрузился ли элемент на страницу при выполнении операций, элемент появляется после нажатия на чекбокс, это проверка на то, что появился ли элемент после нажатия на чекбокс

Answer (score 0):

Решилось так:

```
public class Test{

    public int x;

    public void setx(int x){
        this.x=x;
    }
```

//public  String xpath= "xpath" + x + " xpath"; заменено на:

```
public String xpath() { 
return = "xpath" + x + " xpath";
}

}
```